# django NOT NULL constraint failed: " ............... "

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm new in django and I want to ask you the following question.

I have two models: monthly income, that rappresents my single item monthly income and total montly income, that rappresent the summ of all items monthly income.

My models.py is the following:

```
from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField

class Vendite(models.Model):

    ricavi_dalle_vendite = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=True)
    ricavi_dalle_vendite_01 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_dalle_vendite_02 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)


class Totale_Vendite(models.Model):
    ricavi_tot_dalle_vendite = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=True)
    ricavi_01 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_02 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
```

My views is the following:

```
def ricavi_dalle_vendite(request):
    items = Vendite.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = VenditeModelForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             print("Il form è valido")
             new_input = form.save()

    else :
        form = VenditeModelForm()

    data_jan = list(Vendite.objects.aggregate(Sum('ricavi_dalle_vendite_01')).values())[0]
    data_feb = list(Vendite.objects.aggregate(Sum('ricavi_dalle_vendite_02')).values())[0]
    jan = data_jan
    feb = data_feb
    total_income = Totale_Vendite(ricavi_01=jan, ricavi_02=feb, id=1)
    total_income = Totale_Vendite(ricavi_01=jan, ricavi_02=feb, id=1)
    total_income.save()

    context= {
        "form": form,
        'items': items,
            }
    return render(request, "app/vendite.html", context)
```

The code works well, but when I'm going to delete the first items inserted in the models "Vendite" django give me the error NOT NULL constraint failed: app_totale_vendite.ricavi_01.

I think that the error is about my constraints "id=1" in my views, but I need to have in Totale_vendite model only a row, that update itself if I add or delete an item monthly income.

How can overcome this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `aggregate` returned `None` for field `ricavi_01` (in other words `data_jan == None`) and your schema doesn't allow this field to equal `Null`. Simply modify your code to use default value if aggregate return nothing:

```
jan = data_jan if data_jan else 0
feb = data_feb if data_feb else 0
```

Comment: Great, @Charnel . I have resolve the problem and ì even more important I have learned a new thing thanks to you.

Comment: Glad to help! You can accept the answer if it was useful.

Comment: Done it, enjoy @Charnel